# erro classe abstrata (invalid new-expression of abstract) C++

Tags: c++, classes, factory

Bom estou com um erro nas minhas 3 classes filhas(dvd,jogos,carro) de uma classe mãe chama locadora.
Estou tentando utilizar o factory method e gera o erro no new com seguinte mensagem: invalid new-expression of abstract class type no dvd no jogo e no carro.

```
Produto* CriarNovoProduto(){
char letra;
do{
  printf("QUAL PRODUTO?:\n");
  printf("(J)OGO  (C)ARRO  (D)VD\n");
  letra=getchar();
  letra=tolower(letra);
  }while(letra!='j' && letra!='c' && letra!= 'd');
   switch(letra){
            case 'j':
             return new Jogo();
            case 'c':
              return new Carro();
            case 'd':
              return new Dvd();
            default:
               return NULL;
          }
         }
```

(não sei se posso postar link com o  código completo mas de qualquer forma: https://ideone.com/XLGAoI )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a função "getpreco" não foi refeita nos filhos